# How to load video from IIS virtual directory?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, virtual-directory

I have a .net core web application hosted in IIS. I save all uploaded files (images and videos) in specific folder. I've added virtual directory for that folder in IIS. The problem is, html video tag cannot load the video from server, But images are fine. I've also added`.mp4` MIME Type in IIS.

**Note** Browser opens download dialog when I enter video url directly in browser. `Uploads` is virtual directory.

**UPDATE**

Here is the html code for video loading

```
<video width="436" height="253" controls autoplay class="main">
      <source src="http://mywebsite.com/Uploads/videos/2/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: what does the network tab (F12 devtools) tell you ? Do you see a call to the .mp4 file? Does it have an http status 200 or other ?

Comment: there is a call to .mp4 file and the response is 206

Comment: Sounds ok. If the video element correctly starts a network call for the mp4, I presume it is just some display thing. Did you specify the controls attribute or autoplay ? Did you set a width? etcetera

Comment: sounds like you're linking directly to the file.  Use an embed tag, maybe?

Comment: could you please share your sample code of how you loading the video on your page? you could refer this link : https://www.jauernig-it.de/asp-net-coreiis-serving-content-from-a-file-share/

Comment: @AardVark71 Yes, I've added controls and autoplay attribute to video tag. When the page loads completely, browser try to downlod video not play it in browser

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Yes, it's done.

Comment: try to restart the world wide web publishing service. try to run failed request tracing in iis and share the log detail. make sure you assign the iis_iurs and iusr permission to the upload folder.